# Javascript to hide a popup

Tags: javascript, php

I have this script to show a popup as the page loads:

```
$(function ()
{
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popup').show();
    $('.close').click(function ()
    {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
    });
    $('.x').click(function ()
    {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

And it works fine. Now I've been asked to hide the popup if the user has already seen this page, so I've appended to the above code

```
 function hidePopup()
 {
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
 }
```

But when I call it from a PHP script, it does not show the popup but the overlay is still there.

The PHP code is as follows:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['seenPopup']))
{
    echo "<div class='popup'>
                <div class='cnt223'>
                <img src='./images/close.ico' alt='quit' class='x' id='x' />
                    <div class='divScrollabile'>
                    <p><h3>
                POPUP TEXT HERE
                        <a href='' class='close'>Chiudi</a> 
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
    $_SESSION['seenPopup'] = true;
}
else
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                hidePopup();
                </script>";
}
```

Comment: host in var if user have saw, them is is true dont execut, else execute...did you try?

Comment: mention that php code too

Comment: I don't know how to do it. In the PHP I've just created a $_SESSION variable to store wheter the user has seen the page or not. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Set a cookie when the user clicks the "Close" button. Don't show the overlay when the cookie is set

Comment: kerbholz thank you, but I think it's exactly what I've done

Comment: I don't see you setting a cookie anywhere in that code nor checking if a cookie has been set and thus not showing the popup. You store in a session which is gone when the user visits your page next time. IMHO a popup should be handled clientside, not serverside

Comment: @AlessandroF How exactly are you running this file as? As `http://` (being an HTTP protocol) or directly into your browser as `file:///`? Btw, you need to use the `@username` to respond to someone directly. Otherwise, they might not see it. What does php's error reporting reveal?

Comment: @KamranAzari Concerning [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24902351). Why are you removing the "session" tag that I added earlier? Edit: So if the session tag is to be taken out, as would/should the "php" tag then.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank you. I'm using the HTTP protocol. I'm somewhat forced to use SESSION since my boss does not want to store anything on the client's machine. I've tried the code provided by the user below but it still does not work. I do not want to disturb you, but do you have any solutions?

Comment: @AlessandroF I take it that the file extension is `.php` correct? Can you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your php file(s) and see if errors show up. Also, look at your developer tools to see if anything shows in there. I am not a JS guy, but that's something that is often said. I am mostly a PHP guy. Also look at the HTML source.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes it is .php, and nothing is being displayed when added those functions. Thank you anyways, I'm not a JS guy too but they have to save on developers' salaries

Comment: @AlessandroF Ok. Well, a last ditch effort would be to check if the jQuery library is loaded and it does load your JS. Because that looks to be jQuery code/syntax. What did your HTML source reveal? Have you done that to see what does pass by? Did you check for errors? There are too many things that can go haywire when using jQuery/JS/PHP and sessions. Sessions are usually used for 2 or more pages or wanting to use the same session array in a single file with Ajax. I can't debug / test this for you, sorry.

Comment: I noticed `if (!isset($_SESSION['seenPopup']))` and `$_SESSION['seenPopup'] = true;`. Those seem to contradict each other. It's basically saying "if it's not set, then the session is true". If you're going to use sessions, first check to see if it's set and possibly equal to something. If it's set/not empty, show them something. Else, show/do something else. Btw, the edit that was made by someone else, is causing harm  to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `overlay` in `hidePopup` function, so change your code to this or something similar :

```
function hidePopup()
 {
    var overlay = $("#overlay");
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Open the web console (F12) and type hidePopup(); what you get? first, make sure the hidePopup() exist and works

Comment: Dos the popup hide when you call hidePopup() in the console?